# Формула текущей позиции пружинного маятника

Tags: алгоритм, математика, физика

Нужна формула для нахождения текущей позиции горизонтального затухающего пружинного маятника. В виде алгоритма.

Comment: Это физика смотри - закон Гука.

Comment: Я дико извиняюсь, а можно пояснить для тех, кто в танке, и не может в физику?

Comment: А что там пояснять? Все очевидно!

Comment: Эм, ну например Википедия даёт либо формулу тонкого растяжимого стержня (F=k∆l), что не то. Либо тензоры и прочий ужас.

Comment: Я тоже таки дико извиняюсь, но просить помощи по физике на форуме программистов — это двойная хуцпа.

Comment: Та какой там тензор - проекция обычной затухающей синусоиды.

Comment: Вопрос по физике, слово «алгоритм» прибавлено сбоку, чтобы сделать видимость онтопика.

Comment: Мне нужен был именно алгоритм, а не формула. И здесь есть вопросы по физике. Поищите по тегу "физика".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Гугл: затухающие колебания.

Как обычно, готового решения вам никто тут не предложит.

Ваша формула:

```html
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML-full"></script> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({"HTML-CSS": { preferredFont: "TeX", availableFonts:["STIX","TeX"], linebreaks: { automatic:true }, EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile ? 10 : 50) }, tex2jax: { inlineMath: [ ["$", "$"]], displayMath: [["$$","$$"]], processEscapes: true, ignoreClass: "tex2jax_ignore|dno" }, TeX: { noUndefined: { attributes: { mathcolor: "red", mathbackground: "#FFEEEE", mathsize: "90%" } }, Macros: { href: "{}" } }, messageStyle: "none" });   </script>

$$ x = A_0 e^{-\beta t} \cos(\omega t - \phi_0)  $$
```

За подробностями к ссылке [2](http://ens.tpu.ru/POSOBIE_FIS_KUSN/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B.%20%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/03-1.htm)

Прочие ссылки:

- [Один](http://www.distedu.ru/mirror/_fiz/phdep.ifmo.ru/electr/70_lekzia_7.htm)
- [Два](http://ido.tsu.ru/schools/physmat/data/res/mehanika/uchpos/text/7_5.html)